# New branches always point to master

Tags: git, github

I'm reading the documentation and do everything by the book when creating new branches for my forked local repo, but no matter how many new branches I make, the head keeps pointing to master and even if I have 10 branches, making changes in one affect all of them.
Its tempting to just remove the directory and clone the repo again, how I usually deal with these problems, but for once I wanna try to solve the problem. Any help appreciated

Making a branch

```
git checkout -b *branchname*
```

Cheking the head

```
git branch -v
```

Everything points to one place

```
53f61b4 Merged *repository name* into master
```

Now after doing some changes, lets say on branch *branchname*, and not commiting any changes, if I switch back to master

```
git checkout master
```

It shows the changes made in the *branchname*

Comment: So what exact commands have you used, and what was the result?

Comment: I go with
git checkout -b branchname
after that I can type git branch -v and all branches show <br/>
53f61b4 Merged *repository name* into master

Comment: Please *edit the question* to give as much information as possible, allowing others to try to recreate the issue.

Comment: its going to be hard to recreate everything, I've been working on this project for a while, I mostly just merged the branches I was done with and after a while realized that changes in new branch are reflected in all branches

Comment: That's not what the question says - it only mentions creating a new branch. If you can find an example of creating a new branch, updating it, and _still_ having all your branches on the same commit, please tell us how to reproduce it.

Comment: It might be hard, but if we can't reproduce it we can't help you fix it.

Comment: I think I've guessed the problem now, _but I shouldn't really have to guess_.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I am sorry that you had to work the extra mile to get what my problem was. 
Sorry for not explaining it properly, I had some assumptions that were fundamentally wrong,
Cheers

Comment: No problem - asking good questions is difficult. I was just trying to give constructive feedback, not beat you up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a branch, it points to the commit where it starts. If you use `git checkout -b <branchname>`, that commit is just HEAD.

Until you actually commit something new to your branch, it won't diverge from your other branches. A branch is a *label*, and several can point to the same place. Just creating a branch doesn't generate an empty commit or anything.

This is described in some detail [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#Creating-a-New-Branch) - there's even a picture showing exactly this situation.

---

About your edit - firstly:

> Now after doing some changes, lets say on branch branchname, and not commiting any changes, if I switch back to master ... It shows the changes made in the branchname

what do you mean *it shows*? What shows? What did you type? You're hiding your actual problem in some unstated assumption. Unless you say what you did, and what actually happened, it's unnecessarily hard for people to help you.

Secondly:

> ... It shows the changes made in the branchname

No, no it doesn't. You still haven't said what you actually see, but if you didn't commit anything, there *are no changes* on either branch.

What you've done is modify your working copy. These are just normal local files.

Since both branches point to the same commit, you can switch between them freely without touching your working copy. Until you commit them though those changes don't belong to any branch, and aren't even really under git's control. They're just local files.

Use `git add` to stage your changes in the index, and then see what happens when you try to switch branches.

In general, you need to add and commit changes for git to track them.